# Lens: Does this filteredHas combinator already exist?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Does this combinator already exist somewhere in [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) or in another library?

```
filteredHas :: Lens.Fold s i -> Lens.IndexedTraversal' i s s
filteredHas fold f val =
    case val ^? fold of
    Nothing -> pure val
    Just proof -> Lens.indexed f proof val
```

It's useful for cases where one may wish to modify a value only if it has a certain sub-value.

i.e it can replace code like

```
Lens.filtered (Lens.has part) %~ \x -> something (x ^?! part) x
```

with `filteredHas part %@~ something`.

Comment: Maybe it's better to open issue at `lens` GitHub repository and receive answer with either link to such operator or explanation why it doesn't exist: https://github.com/ekmett/lens/issues

Comment: @Shersh: Thanks for the suggestion. Opened an issue at https://github.com/ekmett/lens/issues/806